# MATLAB: Error in fig2texPS

Tags: matlab, latex

I want to use fig2texPS to export plots from MATLAB to LaTeX. I copied the the script to D:\Eigene Dokumente\MATLAB\fig2TexPS and added this folder as a path in MATLAB. Unfortunately, I receive the following error:

```
>> fig2texPS()
Undefined function 'find' for input arguments of type 'matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Line'.

Error in fig2texPS (line 526)
lsh = double(find(handle(lshandles),'-class','graph2d.lineseries')); % find plots
```

PS: I use a version of the script which was updated in order to work with pdtlatex (http://pastebin.com/xK6KxxBT) that I found in the MATLAB Central File Exchange. The same error also occurs when I use the original script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the answer you are looking for, but there is the marvelous [matlab2tikz](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz) that does the job of conversion of figures quite nicely, which you could use as an alternative to fig2texPS.

Answer (score 0):

I also use the function `fig2texPS.m` and it works very well. It might be an answer for your question to use an older version of Matlab. I am using 2013b and it works. While I have tried this function with Matlab 2015a, I was getting the same error message.

I hope my answer helps you with your problems.